# sympyのsympy.plotはプロット出来ない？NameError: name 'Integral' is not defined

Tags: python, python3, sympy

以下のコードでは行列計算を行っており、最終的に行列 `X_` の成分を求めています。
成分はシンボル `t` の関数で、続くコードではその関数のグラフを描き出そうとしています。

しかし、どういうわけか "NameError: name 'Integral' is not defined" というエラーが出てきます。

理由として思い当たるのは `X_` を表示すればわかる通り、インテグラルが取れていないことです。つまり、sympyなのに数値計算せずに式だけしか返してくれていません。

どうすればプロット出来ますでしょうか？

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A=sp.Matrix([[-2,0],[0,-1]])
B=sp.Matrix([[1],[1]])

X0=sp.Matrix([[1],[0]])

t=sp.symbols("t")
T=sp.symbols("T")
u=1

At=A*t

X=At.exp()*X0
    
AtT=A*(t-T)

X_=sp.exp(At)*X0+ sp.integrate(sp.exp(AtT).exp()*B*u,(T,0,t))

num_fac_2=len(X_)
fucs_2=[]
for i in range(0,num_fac_2):
    fucs_2.append(X_[i])
    sp.plot(X_[i],(t,0,10,0.1))
```

Comment: 質問のコードには、"integral"という文字列が含まれていないのですが、「NameError: name 'Integral' is not defined」というエラーはどこで発生するのですか？

Comment: 式のなかにintegralを含んだままではグラフ化できないのかもしれませんね。sympy.plottingにてエラーが発生していますね。

Comment: > 理由として思い当たるのは,X_を表示すればわかる通り、インテグラルが取れていないことです。つまり、sympyなのに数値計算せずに式だけしか返してくれていません。 →  Tもtも変数なのでそれで良いのではないでしょうか？

Comment: `print(type(sp.integrate(sp.exp(AtT).exp()*B*u,(T,0,t))[0]))` を実行してみれば分かるかと思いますが、`sympy.integrals.risch.NonElementaryIntegral` と表示されます。つまり、`Integral(exp(exp(2*T - 2*t)), (T, 0, t))` は「初等関数では表現することができない積分」という事です。今回、`sp.exp(AtT).exp()*B*u` は exponential integral(指数関数を含む積分によって定義される特殊関数)で、現行の sympy ではプロットできない様です(Mathematica では可能)。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

次の二つのように方針を決めると、下に示すように書けます。

- 行列のまま積分するのをあきらめて、要素ごとに積分する。
- `integrate`で積分を行うのをあきらめて、ただ単に`Integral`で積分を表す。

```py
import sympy as sp

A = sp.Matrix([[-2, 0], [0, -1]])
B = sp.Matrix([[1], [1]])
X0 = sp.Matrix([[1], [0]])

t, T = sp.symbols("t T")
u = 1

At = A * t
AtT = A * (t - T)

constant = At.exp() * X0
integrand = AtT.exp().exp() * B * u

X0_ = sp.Matrix([[c + sp.Integral(i, (T, 0, t))]
                  for c, i in zip(constant, integrand)])

for x in X0_:
    sp.plot(x, (t, 0, 10, 0.1))
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力][image: 画像の説明をここに入力]